# Finding island of trues in sea of falses

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity

Suppose I have an array that looks like

```
[False, False, ..., False, True, True, True, ..., True, False, False, ...]
```

That is, a block of False, followed by a block of True, followed by another block of False.  Any of these blocks can be zero in size.

Is there a sublinear algorithm to find the index of the first True (if it exists)? Such an algorithm could return `len(array)` if no True existed.

I know that if there wasn't a second False block, this can be done in O(lg n) time (and is basically just binary search). But I don't really know how to search for this case online, and I haven't been able to find anything that says such an algorithm exists, or that none is possible.

Comment: Without more context the "blocks of False" is useless, we have to assume a random array of true/false. If the "blocks" thing has more context, knowledge that tells us the sequence is non-random and also something about the block size it _might_ possibly be used to optimize the algorithm, impossibly to say using the available information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, worst case has to be O(n) - whatever order you choose for examining the array, it's possible there is a single true inside and it can end up being in the last index you look at..

Edit: actually, even simpler worst case is where there is no true in there at all. You can't determine that without looking at every single element of the array.

Comment: I don't think this is an accurate argument.  If I'm binary searching an array of integers for the number 5, even if there's only one 5, and it's at the last index I look at, it still doesn't take O(n) time.

Comment: But that case is different - each time you look at one index, you can discard the entire left or right-hand part of the array depending on what you find. In this case, if you find a false, you don't know which side you're on, so you can only discard the single index.

Comment: @SteveD: binary search uses additional out-of-band information about the array and its contents, namely that the array is sorted. We don't have any such information in this case.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I agree we don't have the sorted information, but we do have out-of-band information about the array as presented in the question. This argument is not really convincing that no such algorithm exists. For example, it's easy to see that if you can find just one True in the array, then the rest can be done in better than O(n).

Comment: And I see now the edit to this answer, which shows when finding "just one True" doesn't work, indeed the worst case is O(n).  +1.